# Javascript changing background color

Tags: javascript

I tried to change a background color with javascript and it didn't work out, and after lots of trying I didn't find any problem.

```
var x=1;

switch(x) {
    case 1: {
        document.getElementsByClassName("gallery").style.backgroundColor="blue";
    }
}
```

I don't see any need to copy html or css to here. If this code is fine though I'll edit and add the other codes.

Edit: Html added, as you requested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>פרדס מרים ומרדכי</title>
<link href="../../CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript" src="Album1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="menu">
        <pre class="menu1"><a class="menu1" href="../../index.html">דף הבית</a>             <a class="menu1" href="../../HowToArrive.html">כיצד מגיעים</a>             <a class="menu1" href="../../HowItAllBegan.html">איך הכל התחיל</a>             <a class="menu1" href="../../Albums.html">אלבומי תמונות</a>             <a class="menu1" href="../../Contact.html">צור קשר</a></pre>
        </div>
      <div id="main">
        <div class="gallery_bg">    
            <div class="gallery"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: CSS added. I believe you only need the part referring to the gallery class. The whole code is really long, if you need it I'll add it too, just say.

```
        .gallery {
            width:550px;
            height:550px;
            -webkit-background-size: 550px 550px;
            -moz-background-size: 550px 550px;
            background-size: 550px 550px;
            border:#fff 3px solid;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
```

Comment: Don't you have to iterate through the set and apply the new style to each element one-by-one?  The `getElementsByClassName` function returns an array.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

`document.getElementsByClassName("gallery")` returns `NodeList` , and it is like `Array` , so you can do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("gallery")[0].style.backgroundColor="blue";
```

Or do it in loop:

```
var galleries = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery");
var len =  galleries.length;

for(var i=0 ; i<len; i++){
   galleries[i].style.backgroundColor="blue";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything. I changed my code to your first one (with the [0]) but there is still no result. There is only 1 element in this class for now, so i suppose 0 is the right number..
Furthermore, I tried to change it to Id and it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us the html and css OriShuss, if this doesn't work, it's likely a problem with one of those

Comment: I'll edit and add the HTML. But this is the weirdest problem ever- I have checked all my codes on fiddle (html, css and javascript) and on fiddle the division really WAS blue. If you check my website though, 
http://www.pardesmm.com/galleries/1-%20%D7%97%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%AA/Album1.html
you can notice that the division (in the middle) is grey, in the page color. So the code affects fiddle but doesn't affect the internet? (I added a border to the website so you can see what division I refer to).

Comment: @OriShuss: mate, it looks like the JS is getting executed before the element is created. Try moving the `script` tag to just before the end of the body tag (`</body>`) or put the entire thing into a function and call it on page load. You can refer to my updated answer for details on how to do it on load.

Comment: Thanks alot! So, do all <script> tags have to come at the end unless they specify a function?

Comment: @OriShuss: Not in all cases, but it is safer to put all scripts that manipulate an element (like change its style/content etc) at the end/call them on load. This will make sure that the element is created and available for manipulation by that time.

Answer (score 0):

"document.getElementsByClassName" work like an array if you want to change the backgrouond color you have to use loop to change the color.

Solution:
const ulList = document.getElementsByClassName("list-item");

```
    for(var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++){
    ulList[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
```